# Is this function Riemann-Steiltjes integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let the functions $f, \alpha : [0,3] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined like the below

$f(x)  = \lfloor 2\cos({\pi x \over 6})\rfloor$

$\alpha(x)  =
\begin{cases}
1  & \text{$ x \in [0,2)$} \\
3x & \text{$x \in (2,3]$} \end{cases}$

Find the value of the $\int_0^3 f d \alpha$ .

---

I'm trying this over and over to find the value, But My result always Not integrable.

I drew each graph of them and conclude the form of the $f(x)$'s graph on $(0,3]$

$f(x)  =
\begin{cases}
1  & \text{$ x \in (0,2]$} \\
0 & \text{$x \in (2,3]$} \end{cases}$ also $f(0) = 2$

Hence only should I do is Among of the $[0,3]$'s refinement, just considering the interval $[2-\epsilon, 2+\epsilon]$ because the Riemann-Steiltjes Sum would be $0$ if the point is not include that interval.

$U(f,p,\alpha)$ = 5 and $L(f,p,\alpha) = 0$

Therefore, this function not integrable.

But the answer was This function is integrable and Its value is$ 5$

What the point do I have a mistake? Any help would be apprecaited. Thanks.

Comment: For the classical definition, $f$ is indeed not Riemann–Stieltjes integrable with respect to $\alpha$. But the [generalised Riemann–Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Generalized_Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral) deals with it (assuming that $\alpha(2)$ be defined). Check carefully which version is used.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, Following the classical R-S definition and assuming the $\alpha(2)$ is defined as $1$ or $6$,  Is this case also R-S not integrable?

Comment: By the classical definition, whenever the integrand and the integrator have a common discontinuity the integral doesn't exist. Here, both $f$ and $\alpha$ have a jump discontinuity at $2$, regardless of how $\alpha(2)$ is defined.

Comment: Ah yes! My guess was right. Thanks for your reply.